# Stored procedures for IPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I want to call stored procedures for validations in my app. I'm using Ultralite database in my application which does not support stored procedures.

I found only SQLite and Ultralite database are acceptable by iOS. Is that true?

Please suggest me the possible ways to access database which can hold stored procedures.

I'm new to iOS development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is , You can call a stored procedure from **remote SQL server**.

please see the details [here](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2011/06/07/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx-version-2-0/#more-162) or you can write **Sub-Queries** instead of Stored procedure